# Each K8s POD consume same message published on a SNS topic

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-sns, kubernetes-pod

I am new to SNS. I am basically publishing a message on an SNS topic. Now I have 3 Kubernetes pods in my application.

I would like each of these pods to consume the message published on the topic. Being new to SNS, I don't have any idea if it is possible to make 3 individual pods consume the same message published on the SNS topic.

Could anyone please give any pointer regarding this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to create an SQS queue for each of your pods and subscribe the SQS queues to the SNS topic.
Then you would get the messages in each pod on its own queue.

Comment: thanks for your response. Those PODs are not static, they keep changing on each deployment. So could you please elaborate in detail, how can this be achieved?

Comment: Those pod will still connect to the same SQS queues, in their configuration point them to the correct queue.
This is a "fanout" model often used in queues. A typical example is video transcoding service: you receive a video , you send a message in SNS, you create an SQS for every resolution / file format you want to encode, behind each queues you have several encoding process.